# POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=<my_key> 404 (Not Found) when apk is installed

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I am developing an Ionic app with firebase. I am using angularfire for this. While I was developing the app everything was fine, but when I tried it on a mobile with the apk, it's showing the following error:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=<my_key> 404 (Not Found)
```

Why this error is showing after building apk? What are the mistakes I made?

Comment: did you put youre key in there?

Comment: DO you have access to the internet inside your phone? also, what the rules inside config.xml ? like do you have ` <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/><allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>`

Comment: @SecretCoder yes

Comment: @Al-Mothafar Yes I have these

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All I need was a cordova plugin called [whitelist](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/). Everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If you use polymerfire, try logging the error code using this:

`var errorCode = error.code;
 var errorMessage = error.message;
   console.log(errorCode);
          console.log(errorMessage);`